# Can't insert data into database with PHP using a query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Everything works up until the query for inserting the data into the database. I've tried using only one variable to insert into the database and I still can't get the query to run correctly. It may just be a simple typo that I'm missing but I can't seem to find it.

HTML select page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #container {
   margin: 15px auto;
   width: 700px;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   border-radius: 3px;
  }

  .title-container {
   padding: 20px;
  }

  .title {
   font-size: 28px;
   margin: 20px;
  }

  .price {
   color: red;
  }

  img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #submit {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   padding: 15px;
   border: 0;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <form action="checkout.php" method="post">
   <div class="product">
    <div class="title-container">
     <input type="radio" name="game" value="Assassin's Creed II"><span class="title">Assassin's Creed II - <span class="price">$15.99</span><br />
    </div>
    <img src="assassin2.png">
   </div>
   <div class="product">
    <div class="title-container">
     <input type="radio" name="game" value="Assassin's Creed Brotherhood"><span class="title">Assassin's Creed Brotherhood - <span class="price">$19.99</span><br />
    </div>
    <img src="brotherhood.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="product">
    <div class="title-container">
     <input type="radio" name="game" value="Assassin's Creed Revelations"><span class="title">Assassin's Creed Revelations - <span class="price">$24.99</span><br />
    </div>
    <img src="revelations.jpg">
   </div>
   <h4>Enter quantity: <input type="number" size="2" name="qty"></h4>
   <input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="submit">
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP order overview page

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $game = $_POST['game'];
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];
 $_SESSION['sale_game'] = $game;
 $_SESSION['sale_qty'] = $qty;
 $price;
 $subtotal;
 if ($game == "Assassin's Creed II") {
  $price = 15.99;
 } elseif ($game == "Assassin's Creed Brotherhood") {
  $price = 19.99;
 } elseif ($game == "Assassin's Creed Revelations") {
  $price = 24.99;
 }

 $_SESSION['sale_price'] = $price;
 $subtotal = $price * $qty;
 $_SESSION['sale_subtotal'] = $subtotal;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #container {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 15px auto;
   border: 1px solid black;
   overflow: auto;
  }

  #image-container {
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
  }

  #info-container {
   float: left;
   padding: 20px;
  }

  h3 {
   margin-left: 10px;
  }

  p {
   margin: 10px;
  }

  #price {
   color: red;
  }

  #user-info-container {
   clear: both;
   padding: 10px;
  } 

  h2 {
   color: red;
  }

  table {
   margin: 20px auto;
   font-size: 24px;
  }

  input {
   font-size: 18px;
  }

  #submit {
   color: white;
   background-color: red;
   border: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 3px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="image-container">
  <?php
   if ($game == "Assassin's Creed II") {
    echo "<img src='assassin2.png'  width='300' height='170'/>";
   } elseif ($game == "Assassin's Creed Brotherhood") {
    echo "<img src='brotherhood.jpg'  width='300' height='170'/>";
   } elseif ($game == "Assassin's Creed Revelations") {
    echo "<img src='revelations.jpg' width='300' height='170' />";
   }
  ?>
  </div>
  <div id="info-container">
   <h3>Checkout Info</h3>
   <p><strong>Game:</strong> <?php echo $game; ?></p>
   <p><strong>Price:</strong> <span id="price">$<?php echo $price; ?></span></p>
   <p><strong>Quantity:</strong> <?php echo $qty; ?></p>
   <p><strong>Subtotal:</strong> $<?php echo $subtotal; ?></p>
  </div>
  <hr style="clear: both; margin: 10px">
  <div id="user-info-container">
   <h2>Enter your information</h2>
   <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table cellspacing="10">
     <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="fName"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lName"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="address" style="width: 99%"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>City</td>
      <td>State</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="state"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>ZIP</td>
      <td>Email</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="number" name="zip"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" id="submit"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>  
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP insert page

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $game = $_SESSION['sale_game'];
 $qty = $_SESSION['sale_qty'];
 $price = $_SESSION['sale_price'];
 $subtotal = $_SESSION['sale_subtotal'];
 $fName = $_POST['fName'];
 $lName = $_POST['lName'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $state = $_POST['state'];
 $zip = $_POST['zip'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'purchases');
 if (!$con) {
  echo "Not connected to database";
 } else {
  $query = "INSERT INTO orders (Game, Price, Quantity, Total, fName, lName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email) VALUES ('$game', '$price', '$qty', '$subtotal', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email')";
  if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) {
   echo "Inserted";
  } else {
   echo "Not Inserted";
  }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  #container {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <p> 
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant code. Css is clearly not needed

Comment: echo $query; die(); run the query. check the mysql error

Comment: Your query is not escaped, you have to quote input vars. If your game is named with a single quote string query fails.

Comment: @Tobia and we can see he has values such as Assassin's creed, which contains single quotes

Comment: Clean up the code snippets with only relevant codes. And yes, always escape your insert values and especially when you're selling something. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape strings:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'purchases');
        if (!$con) {
            echo "Not connected to database";
        } else {
            $game = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['sale_game']);
            $qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['sale_qty']);
            $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['sale_price']);
            $subtotal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_SESSION['sale_subtotal']);
            $fName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fName']);
            $lName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lName']);
            $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['address']);
            $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['city']);
            $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['state']);
            $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['zip']);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO orders (Game, Price, Quantity, Total, fName, lName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email) VALUES ('$game', '$price', '$qty', '$subtotal', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email')";
            if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) {
                echo "Inserted";
            } else {
                echo "Not Inserted";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use prepared statement and placeholders

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'purchases');
    if (!$con) {
        echo "Not connected to database";
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO orders (Game, Price, Quantity, Total, fName, lName, Address, City, State, Zip, Email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $game);
$stmt->bind_param("d", $price);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $qty);
$stmt->bind_param("d", $subtotal);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $fName);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $lName);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $address);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $state);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $zip);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);


        if ($stmt->execute() === TRUE) {
            echo "Inserted";
        } else {
            echo "Not Inserted";
        }
    }
```